# show message in officejs

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, word-web-addins

I need to show a notification when a particular api is not supported

```
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', '1.9')) {

        }
else
{
 //Show message to the user that this feature is not supported
}
```

Presently fabric UI message banner is not supported by microsoft  , so what is the standard messaging approach for office js applications ?

Comment: Are you using React or Angular framework ? Whatever the case pick your library of your choice and display the banner message. Or you can style your own banner and follow it through out all your components

Comment: No iam not using React or Angular

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own banner using your own logic but one thing you need to take note is to use Office design principles for Add-ins.

Microsoft provided this page as guidelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-design